# How to connect to a Server using XML-RPC through a Proxy Server in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, proxy, xml-rpc, codeigniter-3

I can connect to a XML-RPC Server using this Class:

```
$this->xmlrpc->server('http://www.sometimes.com/pings.php', 80);
```

Now when the server with the client application is behind a Proxy with username and password authentication, how do I modify the above Class?

If I understand the Codeigniter Docs right (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html?highlight=xml%20rpc#CI_Xmlrpc), the Class for example has to be modified to look like this:

```
$this->xmlrpc->server('http://www.sometimes.com/pings.php', 80, 'user:pass@proxy.com', 80);
```

Unfortunately this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Load library first:

```
$this->load->library('xmlrpc');
```

and try something similar to this:

```
$this->xmlrpc->server('http://rpc.pingomatic.com/', 80);
$this->xmlrpc->method('weblogUpdates.ping');

$request = array('My Photoblog', 'http://www.my-site.com/photoblog/');
$this->xmlrpc->request($request);

if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
{
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
}
```

[Sending XML-RPC Requests](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html#sending-xml-rpc-requests)

Actually I can't find why that is not working. It's clearly guiding us what should be done.

Comment: The Library is loaded and everything works fine on my local LAMP stack. Now I moved the Site to a production server which is behind a proxy server and i always get the response: Did not receive a '200 OK' response from remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I made it pull in the following way

```
// Make an object to represent our server.
$server = new xmlrpc_client('/api/sample.php','xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net', 80);

// Set Proxy
$server->setProxy($proxyHost,$proxyPort,$proxyUsername='',$proxyPassword='',$proxyAuthType=1);
```